# MvvmCross: Populating MvxListView with items displays line between rows by default

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Hi I am using MvvmCross for my Xamarin Android development and so far it is good. I am using MvxListView to populate ObservableCollection in my ViewModel and it works just fine.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/chat_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/chat_conversation"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items; SelectedItem SelectedRecipient; ItemClick ItemSelectedCommand" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But now I want to stylize the template used MvxListView and it always displays a line between the rows which I am not drawing in the item template.

chat_conversation.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/Icon"
        local:MvxBind="Src Thumbnail,Converter=StreamToBitmap" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chat_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#030303"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_bubble_other"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/profile_pic" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Anybody has an idea how to get rid of the line between the rows in MvxListView?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

1) If you want to remove divider line use this code :

```
android:divider="@null"
```

2) If you want to add space instead of divider line :

```
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="5dp"
```